# MongoDB GroupBy

Tags: mongodb, angular-meteor

I have mongoDB collection like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : "EkKTRrpH4FY9AuRLj",
    "stage" : 10,
},
{ 
    "_id" : "EkKTRrpH4FY9AuRLj",
    "stage" : 10,
},
{ 
    "_id" : "EkKTRrpH4FY9AuRLj",
    "stage" : 20,
}
```

And I want to group it in

```
stage: 10 in paid 
stage: 20 in unpaid
```

Result should look like this

```
{
    "paid": [
        { 
            "_id" : "EkKTRrpH4FY9AuRLj",
            "stage" : 10,
        },
        { 
            "_id" : "EkKTRrpH4FY9AuRLj",
            "stage" : 10,
        }
    ],
    "unpaid": [
        { 
            "_id" : "EkKTRrpH4FY9AuRLj",
            "stage" : 20,
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would suggest using the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) for this where you'd need to run an initial **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** staged pipeline that uses the operators **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** to create the new arrays, and **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** to evaluate some condition and use the logic to embed the correct documents.

A final **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline step is necessary to prune some of the array elements from the previous pipeline that are redundant, i.e. filter out the [false] values by using the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator.

Consider running the following aggregation pipeline that shows the above in mongo shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "paid": {
                "$push": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$stage", 10 ] }, 
                        { "_id": "$_id", "stage": "$stage" }, 
                        false
                    ]
                }
            },
            "unpaid": {
                "$push": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$stage", 20 ] }, 
                        { "_id": "$_id", "stage": "$stage" }, 
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "paid": {
                "$setDifference": [ "$paid", [false] ]
            },
            "unpaid": {
                "$setDifference": [ "$unpaid", [false] ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

Add the **[`meteorhacks:aggregate`](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate)** package that exposes **[`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method on Mongo.Collection instances. Note, this only works on server side and there is no oberserving support or reactivity built in.

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Comment: Thanks it's worked. also if i want whole object should i pass each key in $cond or is there any option for that

Comment: You can opt for the [`"$$ROOT"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) system variable `"$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$stage", 20 ] }, 
                        $$ROOT, 
                        false
                    ]` but would not personally recommend it as it must be used where resulting documents must not exceed the [BSON Document Size limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size).